# How do I convert this player movement script for touchscreen functionality?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a working player movement script that I made from the free character controller 2D asset script and my own, it works using the A and D keys of the keyboard, for moving left and right.

I want to have this code work for touchscreen mobile phones. Basically, you press the left side of the screen to move left, the right side for right.

I'm still new to C# and can use the help.

Here's my current playermovement script.

Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

[Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;

private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;

private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

public float runSpeed = 40f;

float horizontalMove = 0f;


private void Awake()
{
    m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public void Move(float move)
{
    // Move the character by finding the target velocity
    Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, 
    m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
    m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, 
targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Move our character
    Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to this but one solution could be to use the Input API to get touches:

```
void Update()
{
    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed; 

    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
        bool touchIsOnRightSide = touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2;

        horizontalMove.x = runSpeed;
        if (!touchIsOnRightSide)
            horizontalMove.x *= -1;
    }

}
```

In this code we will loop through all touches and check if they're on the right or left side by checking if the X coordinates of the touch is bigger or smaller than the X coordinates in the middle of the screen and then apply movement in that direction.

Comment: I have no words to mean how much I'm crazy happy now! Just seeing my game work on the phone now and seeing how it looks and feels made me feel so insanely good! Thanks so much my friend <3

Comment: Ah, awesome! That makes me very happy to hear! :) <3